# Как создать не модальное диалоговое окно? (qt)

Tags: c++, qt, qfiledialog

Моя идея: у меня есть 2 окна - main и settings, я хочу чтобы при нажатии на menu bar в main окне вызывалось диалоговое окно settings с выбором директории. При этом, чтобы окно settings не блокировало main окно, чтобы можно было работать и в одном окне и в другом. Хотелось бы, чтобы окно settings было не модальным окном.

Сейчас для этого я использую вызов, который создает модальное окно:

```
QString inputDir = QFileDialog::getExistingDirectory(this, tr("Open Directory"), 
"/home", QFileDialog::ShowDirsOnly | QFileDialog::DontResolveSymlinks);
```

Я знаю, что QFileDialog::getExistingDirectory(): создает именно модальное окно.

---

Моя изначальная задача, чтобы пользователь вызвал меню выбора директории, через диалоговое окно, а потом уже была бы обработка файлов из этой директории.

Подскажите как можно по другому создать диалоговое окно для выбора директории, чтобы оно было не модальным? Может вместо QFileDialog можно использовать что-то еще? Или вовсе должен быть другой подход в моем случаем?

Comment: а какая изначальная задача? Возможно Вам просто нужен QFileSystemModel, что бы отображать список файлов-каталогов?

Comment: Можно создать объект класса QFileDialog, установить нужные свойства (в т.ч. `setFileMode(QFileDialog::Directory)`), и вызвать `show()` (не `exec()`!). О закрытии диалога пользователем, узнать из сигналов объекта.  Но, подозреваю, диалоговое окно будет не совсем то что вам нужно.

Comment: В таком случае, думаю, вам лучше использовать виджет QFileDialog напрямую. Вы не можете контролировать время жизни виджета, если используете статическую функцию вроде getExistingDirectory